# How to change icons'/emojis' location using CSS?

Tags: css, icons, emoji, text-align

I am trying to move the icons in my `/ar` footer to the front of the text.
Here's the url and a screenshot:

http://qarawa-sweets.com/ar/

Image description of the wanted result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMDwn.png

HTML Code:

< span style="color: #f45152; font-size: 11pt;" >< i class="fa fa-whatsapp" style="color: green;" > < /i > 00972-598-301-381 < /span >< /p >

And here is the CSS:

```
.fa, .fab, .fad, .fal, .far, .fas {
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    line-height: 1;
}


I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74168999/how-to-insert-icon-before-text but I couldn't apply it.
```

Comment: can you provide the code?

Comment: The HTML code?

<img draggable="false" role="img" class="emoji" alt="" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/14.0.0/svg/1f4f1.svg">

And here is the CSS:

img.wp-smiley, img.emoji {
 display: inline !important;
 border: none !important;
 box-shadow: none !important;
 height: 1em !important;
 width: 1em !important;
 margin: 0 0.07em !important;
 vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
 background: none !important;
 padding: 0 !important;
}

Comment: Yes all of the code you used to display what is currently being displayed. That code provided doesnt contain your text for that emoji.

Comment: Let us focus just on WhatsApp since it's the one I can't edit.
I used this when I wrote it <span style="color: #f45152; font-size: 11pt;"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" style="color: green;"></i> 00972-598-301-381</span></p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I added (direction: ltr;) to my HTML code and it worked.
This can also be added as CSS in case you can't edit your HTML

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).